# How to save äåö characters in Json file?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to dump everything from scrapy crawler into json file but äåö changes to something like \u00f6.
How do I fix that?

Comment: FYI `\u00f6` is `ö`.

Comment: @khelwood thanks, that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ensure_ascii=False`

**Ex:**

```
import json

data = {"Hello": "äåö"}
print(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False))  # --> {"Hello": "äåö"}
```

**Note:** *If ensure_ascii is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is false, these characters will be output as-is.*

Comment: In some more detail, with `ensure_ascii` your text file is portable to any system, whereas without it you are opening the door for various character-encoding problems. Any *conformant* JSON processor will know that the encoding is guaranteed to be UTF-8, but homegrown scripts by beginners are more or less likely to crash or corrupt the data. Tomorrow you'll be back and ask us why Excel displays your _ö_ as _Ã¶_.